# Is there a way for interface builder to create Leading/Trailing constraints to root view ignoring the margin by default?

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout

In Xcode 6's interface builder whenever I create a leading or trailing constraint to root view it assigns them to its margin. I almost never need constraints at the margin. I want them to end at root view's edge instead. So each time I need to go to Attribute Inspector and uncheck "Relative to margin" option. I need to repeat it a lot for each of my view controller. Like 7 times. I know it does not sound like much, but it makes me a little bit less happy.

Is there a way to make Interface Builder create those constraints that ignore margin by default and stretch to root view's edge?

Comment: I wish! It seems to default to margins forcing you to uncheck it every time =/